# Windows forms Listbox and treeview multiple selection alternate in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, webforms, listbox, asp.net-3.5, multipleselection

I am trying to achieve multiple selection functionality in asp.net as in windows forms. It is required to provide in interface where all possible items are being displayed on one side user selects an item and press a button with ">" text to move the items in a panel of selected items. Similarly on pressing button with ">>" text all items should be moved to selected items panel and vice verse for buttons with "<" and "<<" text. 
Furthermore, when user clicks save button then items in selected items panel are saved in database, while on editing the record items should be placed in exact panel i.e. selected & not-selected items panel.
I hope you got my point, I am trying to achieve this functionality in Webforms with .NET 3.5 but don't know how to start or what to Google.
Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Where is your code ? any try ?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post "don't know how to start or what to Google" I was searching by using keywords like "windows form listbox alternate in ASP.NET for multiple selection" etc found some links like http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=209 but these are related to windows form. I think Events & Controls used in the code are not available in webforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want something like this :

[image]

For implementing this, First Of all i have 2 `ListBox` on my page, `lstSource` & `lstDest`.
After that i add `ListItem` to the `Items` property of `lstSource`, Then i implement buttons code-behinde this way :

```
protected void btnSelectOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lstDest.Items.Add(lstSource.SelectedItem);
}

protected void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (ListItem item in lstSource.Items)
  {
    lstDest.Items.Add(item);
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.
But keep in mind, these are Server-Side controls and they aren't good choice for this goal, you should use `javascript` or `jquery` plug-ins instead.

Comment: Thanks Saman, You got my point very well. But how I can achieve collapsible functionality using this listbox approach? For example I have bound left listbox data from db as "countries with their states in collapsed state" i.e. when country is selected then cities are expanded below country name. User selects a city and presses ">" button then city name along with contry name (in collapsable form) moves to the right pane.

Comment: You should use TreeView ASP.NET control for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In your button click event you can do something like that:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
           if (item.Selected == true)
           {
               //insert your code that adds the selected item to the panel you have
           }
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few things that you have to handle first. Change the selection mode to multiple and handle the postback(if you haven't).